# Why doesn't curl-config --cflags print libcurl's header files directory?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl, linux-mint

I'm trying to include libcurl in my c++ project, and so am trying to find where the header files are located, but running "curl-config --cflags" just prints an empty line, instead of any useful information. I do have libcurl installed, not only because curl-config is included in libcurl and doesn't throw an error when calling it, but running "sudo apt-get install libcurl4" tells me it's already installed, and is the latest version.

I've tried googling this problem but haven't found anyone else with the same issue, I've run "sudo apt-get upgrade libcurl4" and "sudo apt-get update" and still get the same issue, and I've run out of ideas. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

My operating system is Linux Mint Cinnamon. Let me know if you need other info. Thanks!

Comment: Did you find the curl library file? Probably located in either /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib.

Comment: `curl-config --cflags` returns nothing, then no special include paths are required and libcurl include files are located in the system include paths or you did not install libcurl4-dev.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe S.M. found the answer, which in hindsight I should have tried. Apparently, my system already had the necessary header files in its default include paths, meaning there would be no path to include, hence the blank line. I probably should have tested this by seeing if my code completion software detected it, I would've saved the headache! :) For the sake of future programmers with this issue, here's the takeaway: test to see if a library is installed already first, THEN try to install it! Thanks S.M. for the help!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).